# Can you do multiple options for the =if(isnumber(search))) formula in excel?

Tags: excel

This formula looks for the string "BFA" inside cell I3. If found, it returns "BFA"; if not, it returns "No".

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BFA",I3)),"BFA","No")
```

How can I modify this to work for multiple strings at the same time?  For example, if any of {"BFA", "MFA", "BA", "MA"} is found, then return what was found; if not, return "No".

Comment: I don't believe off hand that `SEARCH` can work like that... but you could just nest a few `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(...)))` statements.  Like `IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BFA",I3)),"BFA",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MFA",I3)),"MFA",IF(...`

Answer (score 4):

This is absolutely possible, but I would recommend a different approach:

```
=INDEX({"BFA","MFA","BA","MA","No"},MATCH(1,COUNTIF(I3,"*"&{"BFA","MFA","BA","MA",""}&"*"),0))
```

You can also put the items to look for in a range of cells and their results in the range next to them.  So if you had the following setup:

```
    _____A____  ___B__
1   Search For  Return
2   BFA         BFA
3   MFA         MFA
4   BA          BA
5   MA          MA
6               No
```

Then the formula would look like this:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(I3,"*"&$A$2:$A$6&"*"),0))
```

For making it scalable and updatable I recommend putting what to search for and what that search should return if found in a range as shown.  You could put it on a separate sheet or hide those columns if preferred.

Comment: it's a nice approach - note that the latter formula needs array entry, also with both versions you'd still get `#N/A` error if I3 is blank

Answer (score 4):

You can use this version with `LOOKUP`:

`=IFERROR(LOOKUP(2^15,SEARCH({"BFA","MFA","BA","MA"},I3),{"BFA","MFA","BA","MA"}),"No")`

The `SEARCH` function returns an array of either numbers or errors (depending on whether each string is found or not). When you lookup `2^15` in that array, the match is always with the **last** number, and then `LOOKUP` returns the corresponding text string. If there are no matches, you get `#N/A` and `IFERROR` converts that to "No".

So if you have any cells that contain both "BFA" and "BA", for example, the formula will return the last one in your list, i.e. "BA".

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you are looking for:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("BFA",I3)),"BFA",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("MFA",I3)),"MFA",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("BA",I3)),"BA",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("MA",I3)),"MA","NO")))
```

Although the more nested `If` statements you make, it can get very complex.  You might consider trying a custom formula in the future.

Answer (score 0):

This is `absolutely possible`, but I would recommend a `different approach`:

```
=INDEX({"BFA","MFA","BA","MA","No"},MATCH(1,COUNTIF(I3,"*"&{"BFA","MFA","BA","MA",""}&"*"),0))
```

You can also put the items to look for in a range of cells and their results in the range next to them. So if you had the following setup:

```
    _____A____  ___B__
1   Search For  Return
2   BFA         BFA
3   MFA         MFA
4   BA          BA
5   MA          MA
6               No
```

Then the formula would look like this:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(I3,"*"&$A$2:$A$6&"*"),0))
```

For making it `scalable and updatable` I recommend putting what to search for and what that search should return if found in a range as shown. You could put it on a separate sheet or hide those columns if preferred.

Answer (score 0):

Formula in column B  - copied down the column

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,$D:$D,0)),"Body","Face")

A        B       C    D
                      Face Parts
Ear      Face         Ear 
Mouth    Face         Mouth 
Leg      Body
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21456674)