# Need help getting this Index Match Countif formula to work in Excel

Tags: excel, search, indexing, match, countif

I built my initial formulas based off of the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27867581/can-you-do-multiple-options-for-the-ifisnumbersearch-formula-in-excel/27867960#27867960?newreg=91749f1526a64521a4450f8189b8880f). The following is the example formula a user gave.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(1,COUNTIF(I3,"*"&$A$2:$A$6&"*"),0))
```

This, modified to my data, only give "#N/A" and I'm seeing that the Match function alone gives the "#N/A" if I use a table like the user suggests, but not if I use their first formula that has the data built into the formula. I see that the comment on his answer says something about it, but I don't know how to apply it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you use Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode?

Comment: could you provide us some printscreen of your data and desired output?

Comment: Had you read through these.. [link1](https://exceljet.net/index-and-match) [link2](http://www.randomwok.com/excel/how-to-use-index-match/) ? Sharing some of your file / sample data/output would help to clarify your question too..

Comment: What I believe is being attempted is to determine if the value in Cell I3 contains the characters in Column A (in order) anywhere within the cell.  The COUNTIF will return a vector of ones an zeroes and the MATCH statement will pull the position of the first matching item from that vector.  He then uses that to pick the corresponding value from Column B.  The formula needs to ben entered as an array formula as Scott Craner so astutely noted.

Answer (score 0):

While the question is somewhat open to interpretation, it appears you have a list in A2:A6 which have some values (perhaps characters) and some translations in B2:B6.  I chose the following for A2:B6

```
house   2
bridge  4
3       5
ton     7
are     9
```

If I3 contains "houseboat" and I enter your formula as an array I will get a "2" as a result because "houseboat" has "house" in it.  If I have "3com" in I3, I get 5 and so on.  If I have a value like "Rareton" in I3, I will get 7 (and not 9) since it obtains the first match.

Not a big difference, but I thought I would offer this alternative for looking up partial strings since it uses the FIND function rather than COUNTIF to find the partial strings.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$6,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(FIND($A$2:$A$6,I3,1)),0))
```

This is also an array formula (using [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] rather than [Enter] alone) and is a couple of characters longer than the one you have.